# Display two or more Calendars in a web page?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar

I've used Ajax controllers for displaying a pop-up calendar. I used a Toolkit script manager, textbox and a Calendar extender, but when I used it for the second time I get the error: "Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page." Are there any other ways of displaying a pop up calendar?

```
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtstartdate" runat="server" 
        ontextchanged="txtstartdate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="txtstartdate" 
        runat="server" PopupPosition="Left"></asp:CalendarExtender>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Height="25px" Text="To" Visible="False"></asp:Label>

    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Txtenddate" runat="server" 
        ontextchanged="Txtenddate_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" TargetControlID="Txtenddate" runat="server">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place just one script manager. Then you can use any number (almost :)) of Calendar extenders.